# Is there any package of MWR for solving coupled ODEs with coupled boundry conditions in MMA?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

1.I have problem like below but I don't want to solve it numerically. I need to guess appropriate solution coupled boundary and fitting my solution to ODEs.

```
D[s[x], {x, 4}] + 3*x*D[s[x]] + x^2 s[x] + 1 == 0

D[v[x], {x, 2}] + 3*x^4*v[x] == 0

(* boundaries *)

S[1] f[y, z] + v[1] f[y, z] = g[y, z]

S[0] f[y, z] + v[0] f[y, z] = infinity

& ... ..
```

I know the solution of ODEs and series form of them but boundaries a little bother my solution.
What is important for me commending a way for solution such problem that we assume solution and then fitting solution to ODE and boundary condition such as MWR or other.

2.Is there any package for MWR?
Other ways will be helpful?

Comment: Have you looked at DSolve?

Comment: yes , but i dont find anything.

Comment: i found some codes of MWR in internet but i dont found any thing about mixed boundray condition